# Когда нужно делать clean package Мавеном

Tags: java, maven, сборка

У меня есть непонимание после каких изменений нужно делать clean-package. У меня довольно большой проект и тратить по 10-15 минут на clean-package каждый раз не хочется.

1. Вот открыт у меня проект. Я его собрал. После этого запустил томкат, он взорвался с ошибками. Я переписал файл конфигурации в каталине. После этого я должен clean-package делать? или сразу могу томкат запускать?
2. Подтянул из чужой ветки изменения. Тут конечно понятно нужно clean-package делать по любому. или все таки бывают моменты когда делать clean-package не нужно?
3. Изменяю локальный класс в своем проекте, чтобы изменения посотреть достаточно перезапустить томкат или тоже clean-package делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нет, вы же ничего не изменили в своем коде. Можете сразу деплоить.
2. Да, здесь ребилд нужен.
3. В общем случае да, но если вы пользуетесь intellij idea и запускаете томкат внутри нее, то можно настроить функции live-reload и hot swap. Первая позволяет обновлять ресурсы сервера без перезапуска (проперти файлы, цсс, хтмл файлы и т.д), а вторая позволяет перекомпилировать класс (если не изменилась сигнатура) и обновить его в томкате без перезапуска сервера.